# Merge Search Index (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

We are using SharePoint 2013 with 2 WFEs and 1 Application server. I have noticed that one of the WFE is running out of space and found out that there is a lot of folders with merge that are big and was wondering how long will it take to merge the search index? the **%default** folder is around 400 GB compare to the other WFE which is currently around 140 GB

The location for the folders:

**D:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\Applications\Search\Nodes\1004C9\IndexComponent1\storage\data\SP35f31f197c7b.1.I.0.0\ms\%default**

Here is a screen shot of the folders

[image]

Comment: I am currently having similar issue.  My Index drive is up to 2TB and can not be expanded further.  1.2 TB space is used by merge file and currently has only 80 GB available.  we notice some failed master merges.  what could be our best possible action to prevent the master merge and get back the space used by merge files?  any guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not normal. Is the search service running and healthy on that server? You may want to try changing your topology so that the search service is forced to clean up a bit. Try moving the index location. It may help.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj862355(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks Matt..I will try your recommendation and update the post

Comment: do we have some space requirements for moving the index file location to different drive and cleaning up the merge files?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the script I've described and posted here (make sure you use the detailed flag as shown in the example)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2015/04/15/sp2013-search-index-health-reports-for-monitoring-and-troubleshooting.aspx

From this, check the merge ratio for each part...

Also, you'll see both the physical size and the checkpoint size...

And, look to see if there are any replicas that are *always showing "merging" as true (which would indicate that it is most likely failing to complete)

Finally, make sure that the Application Server Administration Services time job is running once a minute... especially on the primary admin because that is where the Master Merge gets triggered (I have another post called "the most important timer job..." With a script for checking this timer job across servers)